# How to check, how often have dynamically created buttons been clicked, individually and in total?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables, dom, scope

I created a loop with buttons in it. I also created an eventListener that keeps a count for every button. I want something to happen when all buttons have been presses at least 3 times, so I created an if statement that checks if the count is 3 and adds 1 to another count, but the other count stays on 1 even if multiple buttons have been pressed 3 times.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  let btn = document.createElement('button');

  btn.classList.add('buttons');
  btn.id = 'button' + i;

  document.getElementById('box').appendChild(btn);

  let count = 0;
  let count2 = 0;

  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    count++;
    console.log(count);

    if (count === 3) {
      console.log('3');

      count2++;
      console.log(count2);
    } else {

      console.log('not 3');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#box button { min-width: 20px; min-height: 20px; }
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 87%!important; }
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box">
</div>
```

So the count variable works fine, and when 1 button has been clicked 3 times the count2 variable changes to 1, but it stays on 1 and I can't seem to find out why. At the end count2 should be 7, because there are 7 buttons.

Comment: What happens if you replace `let` with `var` for the counts?

Comment: Each click increases `count`. When that reaches exactly 3, you increment `count2`. This will happen never again because the next click increases `count` to 4. Please clarify how exactly you want this to work, because from your description it sounds like you'd need a separate count variable for each button.

Comment: @VladimirKornea When I changed it for both the seperate counts disappeared for all buttons, but now that I've changed it only for the 2nd it works perfectly!

Comment: @ChrisG It automatically creates seperate counts for all buttons (it probably has something to do with let because if I change it to var it doesn't anymore)

Comment: So count2 is supposed to count the number of buttons that have reached count == 3 or more? That works, but using `let` inside { } creates an independent variable for each block (closure). You should ideally move `let count2` outside the for loop, above your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to all the comments which already did point to the OP's problem I suggest a different approach based on storing/updating individual button-counts within a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)-instance.

With introducing [event-delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) on top one would get rid of multiple on the fly (for each dynamically created button) applied event handlers which forces the approach to deal with different counter scopes (handler scope and the `for` block scope).

There will be exactly a single handler subscribed once to a single parent-node's `'click'`-event. This handler keeps track of and handles the various click-count states by looking up a buttons individual click-count.

```js
function createButton(id) {
  let elmNode = document.createElement('button');

  elmNode.classList.add('buttons');
  elmNode.id = `button${ id }`;

  return elmNode;
}
function main() {

  // keeps track of and handles the various click count states.
  function handleButtonClick({ target }) {
    const btnNode = target.closest('button');

    // update a single buttons click count total.
    const buttonClickTotal = clickCountStorage.get(btnNode) + 1;
    clickCountStorage.set(btnNode, buttonClickTotal);

    const clickCountList =  Array
      .from(
        clickCountStorage.values()
      );
    // calculate click count total of all buttons.
    const allButtonsClickTotal = clickCountList
      .reduce((total, count) => total + count, 0);

    // check whether the OP's each button minimum 3 times click applies.
    const isEveryButtonHasBeenClickedAtLeastThreeTimes = clickCountList
      .every(count => count >= 3);

    console.log({
      buttonClickTotal,
      allButtonsClickTotal,
      isEveryButtonHasBeenClickedAtLeastThreeTimes,
    });
  }
  const clickCountStorage = new Map;

  const root = document.querySelector('#box');
  // make use of event delegation ...
  // - a single eventhandler subscribed once to
  //   a single parent node's 'click' event.
  root.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick)

  for (let elmNode, i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    elmNode = createButton(i);

    // establish a new button reference related click count.
    clickCountStorage.set(elmNode, 0);

    root.appendChild(elmNode);
  }
} 
main();
```

```css
#box button { min-width: 20px; min-height: 20px; }
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 87%!important; }
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Peter, This code works perfect with my code. Just one question. I have this program that starts with one button. It's a form and everytime I press a button I created it makes a new answer button, but when I tried merging it, the count only worked for the first button not for every button created after. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @TLausie ... I don't know your current code. But the above approach is supposed to work for any DOM / button creation scenario due to its approach of having a single source of truth. A single storage where each of a button's initial click-count state gets set (by this elements reference) once, at each button's creation time. And at click time a button's click count gets updated via reference and storage as well. Just make sure you have a setup which exactly follows the just given description.

Comment: I figured it out thank you! Only the looping problem now.

Answer (score 1):

as Vladimir implied in the comments its a scoping problem.

The variable count is only declared inside the event listener, so later on when you press different button your code does `count++` for a different count variable.

To solve this declare `var count` instead of `let count` - that will make it global.

Or declare the count variable before the `for` loop.

BTW: make sure to stop updating `count` as it gets to 3, since it wouldn't update `count2` if it gets to 4 or above

Comment: Yeah I used it and it works perfectly! I'll update it so it won't update the count anymore